# Vuex getter destruct

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store

I'm using Vue.js with Vuex and wondering is there a way to destruct **getters**, just like **actions** do?

This getter:

```html
  doneTodosCount: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => {
      .....
  }
```

to become something like this:

```html
  doneTodosCount: ({rootGetters}) => {
          .....
  }
```

Asking this, because in first example, I don't need first three arguments *state, getters, rootState* but still need to write them to reach the fourth *rootGetters*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because you're not destructuring any object; you need to list the arguments in the correct order.

I suppose you could write a helper function that ignores the first 3 arguments, but to be honest I don't think it's that useful.

```es6
const f = fn => (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters) => fn(rootGetters)

export default {
  doneTodosCount: f(rootGetters => {
    ...
  })
}
```